# AngularJS UI grid pdf export - Long text overflows into adjacent column

Tags: angularjs, pdf-generation, angular-ui-grid

I am having issue while exporting the data in ui grid into pdf. The long words in the columns dont break and overflow to adjacent columns. Is there a way to break the word like in css we do word-wrap: break-word..

I have tried below but nothing worked:

```
exporterPdfDefaultStyle: { fontSize: 16, overflow: 'wordbreak' },

exporterPdfDefaultStyle: { fontSize: 16, overflow: 'linebreak' },

exporterPdfDefaultStyle: { fontSize: 16, wordWrap: 'breakword' },
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Si54Qky5EnBBpRRk1fr9?p=preview) is the sample plunk.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine no ? this is the [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hv2SsFO2PTKshIp9VJzu?p=preview)

I have put data as shown below.If this is not what you mean,please edit the plunk and let me know.

```
 data = [{
    name: "Ethel Price",
    gender: "female",
    company: "Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol Enersol"
  }, {
    name: "Claudine Neal",
    gender: "female",
    company: "Sealoud"
  }, {
    name: "Beryl Rice",
    gender: "female",
    company: "Velity"
  }, ]

  $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
```

This is the pdf :

[image]

**Update :**

Actually there is no such option on the `pdfmake.js`.That means you cannot do this.They have marked this as `feature request`.Hope they'll implement it in future.Here is that discussion.

[**How to wrap the text inside the table cell**](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/204)

Comment: Thanks for your help Sampath. But still the issue remains for long words. Here is the plunk for same. http://plnkr.co/edit/Si54Qky5EnBBpRRk1fr9?p=preview

Comment: did you have a look at that Sampath. This issue becomes more often when the grid has good no of columns hence the width of columns decreases further.

Comment: Please see the `Update` above.

Comment: Thanks Sampath. so got to wait for them to have this request incorporated.

Comment: Was this request ever incorporated?  I am having the same issues with my exported table as well.

Comment: I don't think so @Adrew.